# In Java, why does my constructor not get called when it is in the outer class?

Tags: java, constructor, scope

When running the following code, the constructor:

```
public ItemHandler(Font f)
```

Does not seem to run, or at least not as it should when the variable:

```
private Font font = null;
```

Is in the outer class. If I put it in the "ItemHandler" class it will work, but my main question is, why can't I put it on the class outside of it?

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private Font font = null;
    private Font plainFont;
    private Font boldFont;
    private Font italicFont;
    private Font boldItalicFont;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JRadioButton plainBtn;
    private JRadioButton boldBtn;
    private JRadioButton italicBtn;
    private JRadioButton boldItalicBtn;
    private ButtonGroup group;

    public Window() {

        super("Item Test Program");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        plainFont = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14);
        boldFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
        italicFont = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
        boldItalicFont = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
        textField = new JTextField("Please enter something here.", 16);
        plainBtn = new JRadioButton("Plain", true);
        boldBtn = new JRadioButton("Bold", false);
        italicBtn = new JRadioButton("Italic", false);
        boldItalicBtn = new JRadioButton("Bold and Italic", false);
        group = new ButtonGroup();

        ItemHandler plainItemHandler = new ItemHandler(plainFont);
        ItemHandler boldItemHandler = new ItemHandler(boldFont);
        ItemHandler italicItemHandler = new ItemHandler(italicFont);
        ItemHandler boldItalicItemHandler = new ItemHandler(boldItalicFont);

        plainBtn.addItemListener(plainItemHandler);
        boldBtn.addItemListener(boldItemHandler);
        italicBtn.addItemListener(italicItemHandler);
        boldItalicBtn.addItemListener(boldItalicItemHandler);

        textField.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        group.add(plainBtn);
        group.add(boldBtn);
        group.add(italicBtn);
        group.add(boldItalicBtn);

        add(textField);
        add(plainBtn);
        add(boldBtn);
        add(italicBtn);
        add(boldItalicBtn);

    }

    private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener { 

        public ItemHandler(Font f) {

            font = f;

        }

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {

            textField.setFont(font);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe the `ItemHandler` constructor is not getting run?

Comment: It never runs on debug mode.

Comment: Are you actually doing something that causes the `Window()` constructor to be used?  (`new Window()` somewhere in your program)  If the `Window()` constructor is run, then the `ItemHandler(Font)` constructor will be run four times unless an exception is thrown earlier.  If you believe "it never runs on debug mode", you probably aren't telling the debugger to track this correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's clear what you're asking.  However, note that your constructor

```
    public ItemHandler(Font f) {
        font = f;
    }
```

is modifying a variable that belongs to `Window`, not `ItemHandler`.  Thus, when the same instance of `Window` creates four `ItemHandler` instances, each of those `ItemHandler` constructors will modify the `font` variable in the **same** `Window` instance.  That means that when the `Window` code does this:

```
    ItemHandler plainItemHandler = new ItemHandler(plainFont);
    ItemHandler boldItemHandler = new ItemHandler(boldFont);
    ItemHandler italicItemHandler = new ItemHandler(italicFont);
    ItemHandler boldItalicItemHandler = new ItemHandler(boldItalicFont);
```

they will all overwrite the same `font` variable, which means that only the **last** one counts.  If you were expecting something different, i.e. four different `font` variables each set to the corresponding parameter, that isn't going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

`ItemHandler` constructor runs fine. Problem is that each of its instances try to set value in same `font` field in `Window` instance (they share it) so it will store value set by last created `ItemHandler`.

To avoid this problem move `font` field from `Window` to `ItemHandler`

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    //private Font font = null; // move it from here ------+
    //...                                                  |
    private class ItemHandler implements ItemListener { // |
                                                        // |
        private Font font = null; // <--- [ here ]---------+

        public ItemHandler(Font f) {
            font = f;
        }

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
            textField.setFont(font);
        }

    }

}
```

so each instance of `ItemHandler` will have its own field in which it will store its own information about font.